# error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am getting Error : `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data`

my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.edit1').on('change', function () {
                arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
                var clientid = document.getElementById("client").value;
                account_id = document.getElementById("account_id").value;
                $(this).parent().next().find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", true);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "clientnetworkpricelist/routestatusupdate.php",
                    data: "value=" + $(this).val() + "&rowid=" + arr[2] + "&field=" + arr[1] + "&clientid=" + clientid + "&account_id=" + account_id,
                    success: function (result) {
                        data = jQuery.parseJSON(result); //added line

                        var obj = data;

                        $('#CPH_GridView1_Status' + arr[2]).empty();
                        $('#CPH_GridView1_Status' + arr[2]).append(data.status);

                        $('.ajax').html($(this).val());
                        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

And the JSON output:

```
{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Equalf.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"}{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Equalf.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"}{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Equalf.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"}
```

Comment: Have you pasted your JSON output 4 times?

Comment: Just like the error says - your JSON is invalid. You can't have `}{`s there (what are they for anyway?)

Comment: Did you check JSONLint? Your JSON is invalid. http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that in your JSON output you've got 3 objects:

```
{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Equalf.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"}
{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Equalf.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"}
{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Equalf.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"}
```

which are just placed inline next to each other. Try to modify your PHP script to push all that objects into array and then return that array as output to get result like:

```
[
  {"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Equalf.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"},
  {"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Equalf.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"},
  {"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Equalf.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply can you tell me how to do it

Comment: Probably in PHP script you are printing all objects in an array like: `foreach ($objs as $o) { echo json_encode($o); }`. If I am right, instead of that:
a) if $objs is array use `echo json_encode($objs);`, b) if it's iterator - `echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($objs))`, c) else: let just instead of printing them, push them in loop into array, and then print JSON of that array.

Comment: i am just doing like this 
`$result=array();
$result['status']='<img  src="image/' . $status . 'f.png" />';
$result['seleniumrouteupdate']=$seleniumrouteupdaterow;
$result['routeupdate']=$routeupdate;
echo json_encode($result);`

Comment: Yeah, but you are doing it for every object which you want to return, so instead of that before loop create e.g. array named `$return`,  `echo json_encode($result);` change to `$return[] = $result`, and use `echo json_encode($return)` after the loop.

Comment: it showing the same error :**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
and JSON output `[{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Increasef.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"}][{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Increasef.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"},{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Increasef.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"}][{"status":"<img  src=\"image\/Increasef.png\" \/>","seleniumrouteupdate":"1","routeupdate":"100"}]`

Comment: because you have passed every result to another array. You have to push them into same array. Can you paste your code into e.g. [link](http://pastebin.com)? Then I will fast repair it.

Comment: i paste my routestatusupdate.php http://pastebin.com/BsgzuUNA

Comment: Yeah, I reviewed it and in [link](http://pastebin.com/BjQCkgsD) you've got fixed code - `$return` array is declared before loop and printing is after. Also - mysql extension is deprecated since PHP 5.5 so maybe try to use in next projects PDO or eventually MySQLi.

Comment: thanks now there is no error but the image not showing in the front end